# Whats the point of refresh token in my case

Tags: reactjs, security, jwt, wordpress-rest-api, refresh-token

I'm making web app with frontend in React (GatsbyJS) and backend in Wordpress.
Right now I have authentication with JWT valid for 7 days. Then I've read that I should use refresh token too and make my JWT last for like 15 minutes to follow "best practises".

But the only benefit of doing that I see is better prevention from MITM attacks - the refresh token is used significantly less often, so theres higher propability that the token that attacker steals is valid for 15 minutes instead of 7 days and he has less time to do something with it. But im using HTTPS anyway so I think probability of someone stealing my token this way is very low.

My app would store these tokens in EXACT same way (http only cookie) so attacker can steal both refresh and access token with the same effort. Am I missing something or theres really no sense in using refresh tokens?

I'm planning to add token blacklist so if user logs out once, that token can't be used anymore.

**I'm keeping only user ID in the token.** So after I receive it and decode it on the backend I can check if user is banned, changed password recently, etc. so I can decide if I should give him the data he wants or just put in on blacklist.
I've read that refresh tokens are useful when data in token changes or something but I'm keeping only the ID...

Am I right and I can omit refresh tokens in my case? I think I can't store them more securely than in http only cookie.

If I would be able to use plain http session I would stick to it, but my setup (my frontend isn't connected to wordpress in any way) doesn't allow me to use wordpress rest api with sessions and I have to use these damn jwt tokens.

**Update**
I can see small benefit in using short lived jwt and long lived refresh token for silent refreshing, but it works only when app is continously opened in browser - I'm expecting to keep user logged in for several days. And I can do it without refresh tokens.

Comment: read this https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/

Comment: Exactly this article made me make this thread. I'm not saying that refresh tokens are useless in general, but I'm asking about my specific case

Comment: If your access tokens are valid for long period of time, this is the hazard, since if stolen (can be done not only with MITM attack), it allows the attacker much more room to operate without you to be able to notice (since the accessToken is valid)

Comment: So how are access tokens more vulnerable to stealing than refresh tokens if both are stored in http only cookie on the same domain?

Comment: There is no difference, think that accessToken is the key to your home, if it is valid to long period it is a problem in case of losing it.

Comment: But refresh token is the key to my home too right? If both are stored in cookies and can be stolen then whats the point. If someone steals refresh token he can generate access token. And he can steal refresh token with EXACT SAME effort as access token

Comment: You are correct, but from the article, accessTokens are stored inside apps memory, so it is harder to "steal"